# Bing Speech API Reference

Tags: speech-recognition, bing

I'm looking for the library reference information that tells me the syntax and function of each part of the library - like Microsoft has for its other DLL's that get used in the program. The main page for Bing speech API does not have this or is nowhere near inclusive of all the features of the library.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for documentation for Bing Speech SDK below is the link for documentation
[Bing Speech SDK Client Library C# Documentation](https://cdn.rawgit.com/Microsoft/Cognitive-Speech-STT-Windows/master/docs/SpeechSDK/html/db803a8f-b4c1-a049-00c7-4bf3472fc8cc.htm)

Here is the sample SDK Code in WPF C#  which also includes offline documentation.

[Bing Speech To Text SDK](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/Cognitive-Speech-STT-Windows)

If not helpful, try to further elaborate your question.